# How to dynamically set table column widths in Angular template

Tags: html, css, angular

I am trying to build a table with 6 columns in an Angular 6 component. The first three columns in the table head are fixed widths (in pixels) and my goal is to get the three remaining columns' widths to fill out the remaining table width so that the whole table fills the whole width of the screen, then pass that same value to the child component, which is repeated one time per table row. What's the best way to do this?

It gets complicated because I'm not aware of how to fit this process in with the order of how the views/page renders.

My initial method does this:
The css file assigns the widths of the first three columns in pixels, and the remaining three columns to equal percentages. One the view has been rendered, in my component I use a *ngAfterViewChecked* method to grab the width of the whole table, subtract the first three columns in pixels, and reassign the last three columns a part of the remaining table width through a style tag in the template. This is just for the head. I also pass the value down to the child component which makes up each table row. This seems too excessive- and doesn't even work (it doesn't redraw them to the appropriate widths) And the children components will literally redraw a second time without erasing.

How can I change this to make it function as intended?

My code looks something like this:

```
          <thead>
            <tr #stickyMenu [class.sticky]="sticky">
              <th #title scope="col" id="th0">Monitoring Point</th>
              <th #networkHealth scope="col" id="th1">Network Health<br><small id="more_detail">(Click icon to see more detail)</small></th>
              <th #activeAlerts scope="col" id="th2">Active Alerts</th>
              <th [width]="eachChart" scope="col" id="th3">Flow (ft3/s) <i class='fa fa-info-circle op-icon'
                matTooltip="Velocity will be displayed when there are no flow values available."></i></th>
              <th [width]="eachChart" scope="col" id="th4">Water Temperature (°F)</th>
              <th [width]="eachChart" scope="col" id="th5">Depth Readings (in)</th>

            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>

        <table id="tablebottom" class="table">
          <tbody >
            <tr *ngFor="let item of monitoring_points">
              <app-sensor-summary [mp]="item"></app-sensor-summary>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

CSS

```css
       #th0 { 
            max-width: 175px!important;
            padding-left: 10px;
        }
        #th1 {
            max-width: 125px!important;
        }
        #th2 {

            max-width: 185px!important;
            padding-left: 20px;
        }
        #th3 {

            min-width: 20%!important;
            max-width: 20%!important;

        }
        #th4 {
            min-width: 20%!important;
            max-width: 20%!important;

        }
        #th5 {

            min-width: 20%!important;
            max-width: 20%!important;

        }
        .sticky{      
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            z-index: 12;
            background-color: #fff;
            width:93%;
            padding-bottom: 15px;
            padding-right:20px!important;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
            border-right: 1px solid #cccccc;
            -webkit-box-shadow-bottom:0px 1px 6px grey;
            -moz-box-shadow-bottom:0px 1px 6px grey;
            box-shadow:0px 1px 3px #cccccc;    
        }
```

And in my component:

```
  @ViewChild("stickyMenu", {read: ElementRef}) tr: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild("title", {read: ElementRef}) title: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild("networkHealth", {read: ElementRef}) networkHealth: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild("activeAlerts", {read: ElementRef}) activeAlerts: ElementRef; 

...

  ngOnInit() {...}
  ngAfterViewChecked(){
    this.allChartWidths = (this.title.nativeElement.offsetWidth + this.networkHealth.nativeElement.offsetWidth + this.activeAlerts.nativeElement.offsetWidth)
    this.rowWidth = this.tr.nativeElement.offsetWidth
    this.eachChart= Math.round((this.rowWidth-this.allChartWidths)/3)
    console.log(this.allChartWidths, this.rowWidth, this.eachChart);
  }
    //this.eachChart is then assigned as the 'width' for the last three 'th's in the template above, 
    //AND passed down to the columns in the child component which uses them as well for each table row

  @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
  handleScroll(elementPosition) {
    this.sticky = (window.pageYOffset >= this.elementPosition);
   }
```

Comment: Can you please provide a stackblitz or codepen demo?

Comment: if you don't have an absolute necessity to align things manually please don't. because that's reinventing the wheel. there are lots of different approaches you can try with or without css. I personally recommend using [css flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) on top of that [flex-layout from angular team](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout)